# Having trouble with lists and matrix using xlrd and python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

So my problem is to take a couple of long vectors (each being 15000 rows long) with the appearence:

```
Origin     Destination     Distance
```

and the corresponding values in the columns. I want however to convert these, using Python and the xlrd package, into a distance matrix having

```
          Destination1     Destination2
Origin1   Distance11       Distance12
Origin2   Distance21       Distance22
```

and so forth.

What I have tried thus far is:

```
matrix ={}, i=0, list3 = [], list1 = []
for row in range(orksheet.nrows):
matrix[i] = {}
cell = worksheet.cell(row,2)
distance = cell.value
if float(distance) < 25000:
    list1 = [int(worksheet.cell_value(row,0))]
    list3 = list3.append(list1)
    list2 = [int(worksheet.cell_value(row,1))]
    for l in list1:
        for j in list2:
                matrix[l, j]=math.ceil(worksheet.cell_value(row,2))             
i+=1
```

This works somewhat. When I use
    print(l,j,matrix[l,j]

within the loop over l and j I get what I get the desired values. However, using print(matrix) gives the (general, i.e. the output like that but with the corresponding values instead) output:

```
(Origin, Destination): Distance and sometimes: distance: {}, distance: {},
```

and so on.

What I've perceived is the problem is with the matrix. I cannot understand why it prints like that which I believe has something to do with the lists? The list1 and list2 has len 1 which seems odd to me. I've tried to use list3 to append list1 but it also get len 1.

Regards,

Comment: You shall make your question as narrow as possible. Best is to have small piece of code showing the problem and clear statement, what you perceive as a problem to resolve.

Comment: Thank you. Always a thin line between adding too much information and too little. Edited away approx. 15 lines at least.

Comment: The object is not just to reduce the number of lines in your question. The object is to make your question *focused*. Do not edit the code in the question so that it is no longer valid. `matrix ={}, i=0, list3 = [], list1 = []` is not valid Python. Always post *actual* code that you *actually* ran on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not recommend [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) more for data-manipulation tasks.

For example, the operation you seek in pandas is called [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({'origin': list('aabbccdd'), 'destination': ['d1', 'd2'] * 4, 'distance': np.arange(8)})

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
  destination  distance origin
0          d1         0      a
1          d2         1      a
2          d1         2      b
3          d2         3      b
4          d1         4      c
5          d2         5      c
6          d1         6      d
7          d2         7      d

In [13]: df.pivot('origin', 'destination', 'distance')
Out[13]: 
destination  d1  d2
origin             
a             0   1
b             2   3
c             4   5
d             6   7
```

And to read actual excel file there's [pandas.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-excel) which AFAIR uses xlrd under the hood:

```
df = read_excel('path_to_file.xls', 'Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
```

And there's a lot more to find in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable)

Comment: Thanks alot! Will definetely look more into the Panda documentation and try to use it

Comment: It isn't until now that I've gotten Pandas to work due to some Unicode errors. This solution solves my problem and will be therefore be deemed the accepted answer. Thanks once again immerrr!